# Get text between parantheses using regex

Tags: php, regex

i'm having a problem

i try to get the text between the parantheses

for example this is the input

```
$str = "var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('tlt_map'), { minZoom: 9,  zoom: 14, center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.5802, -7.63349), mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP });";
```

for the output i want :

```
33.5802, -7.63349
```

thank you in advance

Comment: i think you have mistaken js array notation as string

Comment: the question wasn't clear, i updated it now, thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `preg_match` function with this regex `/google\.maps\.LatLng\(([^)]+)\)/` or if you want each number in separated group use `/google\.maps\.LatLng\(([^,]+),([^)]+)\)/`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('tlt_map'), { minZoom: 9,  zoom: 14, center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.5802, -7.63349), mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP });"; 
$newStr = preg_replace('#^.+\.maps\.LatLng\(([^\)]+)\).+$#','$1',$str);
var_dump($newStr);//string(17) "33.5802, -7.63349"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('tlt_map'), { minZoom: 9,  zoom: 14, center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.5802, -7.63349), mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP });"; 

preg_match('/google.maps.LatLng\(([^,]+),([^)]+)\)/', $str, $matches);

echo $matches[1]; // 33.5802
echo $matches[2]; // -7.63349
```